# Treemap rendering

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am trying to render treemap with JSON as

```
[
    {
    "month":"January",
    "north":200,
    "east":150,
    "west":300,
     "south":200
   },
   {
    "month":"February",
    "north":200,
    "east":800,
    "west":300,
     "south":1000
   },
   {
    "month":"March",
    "north":250,
    "east":200,
    "west":400,
     "south":600
   },
   {
    "month":"April",
    "north":690,
    "east":430,
    "west":350,
     "south":1500
   }]
```

I tried to nest treemap to render treemap , using this code,

```
var nested_data = d3.nest()
    .key(function(d) { return d.month; })
    .entries(entries);

console.log(JSON.stringify(nested_data));

var root = {};

// Add the data to the tree
root.key = "Data";
root.values = nested_data;

var treemap=d3.layout.treemap()
    .size([900,900])
    .children(function(d) { 
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(d));
        console.log("child",d.values);
        return d.values
    }) 
    .value(function(d) { 
        return direction.map(function (c) {
            console.log(d.month+d[c]);
            return {x: d.month, y: d[c]};
        })
        .nodes(root)
    })
```

My problem is, on load, I get console log as

[image]

I find no value assigned to x,y,dx,dy though x and y values are logged properly. And I don't understand why child is logged thrice, one as whole array, one as a single and another undefined.Please rectify.

Comment: This has nothing to do with JSON. Please read the usage description of the tag.

Comment: It indeed has nothing to do with JSON. Flaw is with 'children' , which i didn't know how to assign it right.

Comment: Your code is "off".  The `.nodes` call seems to be within the value function, I think you meant it to be on the `treemap` chain.  Also, what is "direction"?

Comment: The month with its north value are printed glued togheter.

Comment: You got it right, That's what i have done.

Comment: The D3 version you are using is v3, and you have an error in your code. It should be d3.layout.treemap()./* all other function calls */.nodes(root); Check this page: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/Treemap-Layout.md#treemap Not inside the value() function.

Comment: D3 v3 API reference: https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/API-Reference.md